# data.table default outer join with setkey, counting rows (tabulate frequency of keys)

Tags: r, data.table, left-join, outer-join

I have two data.tables. I want to use the keys in one to count the occurrences in another.

```
DT1 <- data.table(A = c("v1","v2","v1","v2","v3","v4","v5","v6","v1","v2"),
                  B = c(1,11,111,2,22,222,3,33,333,4))
DT2 <- data.table(C = c("v1","v3","v99"))

setkey(DT1,A)
setkey(DT2,C)
```

Use DT2 to find rows in DT1 returns an outer join.

```
nrow(DT1[DT2,]) #returns 5 (v1*3, v3*1, v99) "v99" not in DT2
DT1[DT2,]

    A   B
1:  v1   1
2:  v1 111
3:  v1 333
4:  v3  22
5: v99  NA
```

Is it possible to force to left join with the same syntax?

Comment: `DT1[DT2, nomatch = 0L]` ?

Comment: Actually this *is* a left join... an outer join would be `merge(DT1, DT2, by.x = "A", by.y = "C", all = TRUE)`. And `v99` *is* present in `DT2`

Comment: thanks mtoto exactly what I was search for.

Comment: You want to **tabulate** the (frequency of) keys in DT1[,A] according to the (partial) list of keys in DT2[,C]. Do you care about tabulating the other keys not included in DT2[,C] ? They get silently dropped, whereas R's `base::tabulate` allows the user to include them (by tweaking `nbins`). This is one case where dt's functionality is less than `base`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to use the keys in one to count the occurrences in another.

```
DT1[DT2, .N, on=c(A="C"), by=.EACHI]

     A N
1:  v1 3
2:  v3 1
3: v99 0
```

Comment: @smci Could you show the code for using tabulate here so I'm clear on what output you are expecting to get?

Comment: For tabulating, the other keys not included in DT2[,C] get silently dropped, whereas R's [`base::tabulate`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tabulate.html) allows including them (by tweaking nbins). How to implement this best? I've been struggling with creating an intermediate column listing the truncated keys, and a nomatch value e.g. 999, then left-joining the result and fixing up the nomatch value for other keys.

Comment: @smci I never use tabulate and so am not sure how it pertains to this case even after reading the docs, but I think some code from you or just the desired output directly might clarify it.

Comment: Frank You can get the code from just typing `tabulate`. Notice how the user can manually tweak `nbins`: run `lapply(1:8, function(nbins) { tabulate(c(3,4,6,1,1,5,3), nbins=nbins) })` and see the range of output. However one limitation is we can't just pass an arbitrary list of levels/bins we want to keep, we rely on the cutoff bins to exclude being a contiguous integer range, which is also painful. For a fast data.table implementation, we'd have to temporarily map(or mutate) an exclude-level value to say `1000+value`.

Comment: @smci (Sorry if I'm not getting it still.) You can choose which values are counted by putting them in the same place DT2 is now: `DT1[.(union(DT2$C, A)), on=.(A), .N, keyby=.EACHI]` gives counts for all values appearing in either table. The keyby part just sorts the result.